# What's the status of beamer's development?

Tags: beamer

As I understand it, maintenance of `beamer` was taken over by Joseph Wright. I am interested to know if a new version is planned, for when,  which features are expected in it, and what's the proper way of submitting suggestions?

Here are some of the things I would like to see, but I am far from being an expert, not even a seasoned user.

- Better control of overlays that would make it possible to design complex animations.
- Columns with automatic overflow from one column to the other
- Tighter integration with `tikz`, or perhaps more material in the manual to explain how graphics can be included.
- Built in support for pop-ups/callouts.
- User defined modes

Comment: This looks 'too broad' or possibly 'opinion-based' to me, I'm afraid. I can outline some things, but will wait to see what everyone thinks.

Comment: Could also be 'off topic' on the grounds it's addressed to essentially one or perhaps two people.

Comment: On the other hand, to me it seems like a good topic for the TeX.SX chat room.

Comment: Not sure if I got the answer to the question in the title: Is there a new version on the planning? Would it be OK if I rephrase to ask "What's the status of `beamer`'s further development?"

Comment: Column issue is deliberately left out. The author discourages such PPT issues. TikZ is in fact tightly integrated most of them know the overlay context (including nodes of callouts!)

Comment: place all your issues and colloborative development here https://bitbucket.org/rivanvx/beamer/issues

Comment: @JosephWright I would really appreciate if you could "outline some things". The question might be to broad, but an answer from the maintainer on what is planned (or not) regarding future releases would nevertheless be very welcome!

Comment: @Daniel (and others) See http://www.texdev.net/2014/01/27/beamer-development/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated above, the best answer is here: http://www.texdev.net/2014/01/27/beamer-development/